# Navigation Drawer "onItemClick" cannot load Support Map Fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, google-maps-api-2

I have navigation drawer when you click item on drawer, It should change Map Type on Google Map in activity.. 
But when i click the item on drawer, Map Type not changing in activity, before i click the drawer.. the map load well and showing marker.. but when i clicked it showing blank map and marker

this my MainActivity

```
public class DirectionRoute extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listViewLeft, listViewRight;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    MyNDAdapterLeft myNDAdapterLeft;
    MyNDAdapterRight myNDAdapterRight;

    MediaPlayer mpMarkerClick;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.direction_route);

    mpMarkerClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button31);

    listViewLeft = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerListLeft);
    myNDAdapterLeft = new MyNDAdapterLeft(this);
    listViewLeft.setAdapter(myNDAdapterLeft);
    listViewLeft.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };

    listViewRight = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerListRight);
    myNDAdapterRight = new MyNDAdapterRight(this);

    //Getting Map From Google
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    listViewRight.setAdapter(myNDAdapterRight);
    listViewRight.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectItemLeft(position);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);


    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mpMarkerClick.start();
        case 1:
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            mpMarkerClick.start();
        case 2:
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            mpMarkerClick.start();
        case 3:
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            mpMarkerClick.start();
        case 4:
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            mpMarkerClick.start();
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewLeft);
}
```

I'm alreadry try in onItemClick method like this

```
 switch (position) {
        case 0:
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            *googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();*
            mpMarkerClick.start();
```

but nothing happen, the map still blank..

i've been see how to change Map Type in Android Google Maps in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_types) and nothing help to my problem,

How should i do to change map type using navigation drawer ?

Comment: Please share your fragment class code.

Comment: The map fragment is in MainActivity(DirectionLayout.class) on the firts load.. the map appear with user location.. but when i click an item on the drawer.. map going blank @Vikram